# Kullback-Leibler distance between 2 distribution of images matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have to calculate Kullback-Leibler (KL) distance of two distribution of different images. Assume I have two image that sizes are 5694x1 and 231x1. Now, I want to calculate KL distance of two distribution in these images. I try to do in matlab but it didnot run. Could you check help me? The problem is the matrix of two distributions are not same size. You can download image test at [imagetest](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oq9rfvbkvjw51cz/AABhwbkFOmqcFVEm9Uasv-Qba)

```
%%Main function to calculate KL
function d=KLdist(firstImg,secondImg)
   h1 =  histogram(firstImg, max(firstImg(:))+1, 0, max(firstImg(:)));
   h2 =  histogram(secondImg, max(secondImg(:))+1, 0, max(secondImg(:)));
   h1(find(h1==0))=1;
   h2(find(h2==0))=1;
   temp = sum(h1.*log(h1./h2));
   temp( isinf(temp) ) = 0; % this resloves where h1(i) == 0 
   d1 = sum(temp);
   temp = sum(h2.*log(h2./h1)); % other direction of compare since it's not symetric
   temp( isinf(temp) ) = 0;
   d2 = sum(temp);
   d = d1 + d2
end

%%Function to calculate histogram distribution
function [h,bins] = histogram(I, n, min, max)
I = I(:);
range = max - min;
drdb = range / double(n); % dr/db - change in range per bin
h = zeros(n,1);
bins = zeros(n,1);
for i=1:n
    % note: while the instructions say "within integer round off" I'm leaving
    %       this as float bin edges, to handle the potential float input
    %       ie - say the input was a probability image.
    low = min + (i-1)*drdb; 
    high = min + i*drdb;
    h(i) = sum( (I>=low) .* (I<high) );
  bins(i) = low;
end
h(n) = h(n) + sum( (I>=(n*drdb)) .* (I<=max) ); % include anything we may have missed in the last bin.
h = h ./ sum(h); % "relative frequency"  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compute a KL divergence on vectors with different sizes. You have to resize your histograms to get identical sizes in both cases.

So set a constant number of bins for all inputs when calling your function histogram.

Comment: How about if I edit by  h1 =  histogram(firstImg, 255+1, 0,255); instead of  h1 =  histogram(firstImg, max(firstImg(:))+1, 0, max(firstImg(:)));

Comment: @user3336190 You impose the same binning for both images, so yes.